# Expectation of the maximum of independent poisson random variables

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, order-statistics

I am trying to prove the following estimation of the expectation of the maximum of independent poisson random variables. I've become interested in this problem while reading Joel A. Tropp's "[An Introduction to Matrix Concentration Inequalities](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01571.pdf)" (Section 5.1.2). The following estimation is used as a key step to show the optimality of the matrix Chernoff bound. I also believe this estimation is also useful in explaining sharpness of the matrix Bernstein inequality.

**Desired estimation:**

Let $X_i, i = 1, 2, \dots, n$ be independent Possion(1)
random variables. Then,
$$
\mathbb{E}\max_{1 \leq i\leq n}X_i \approx C\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}, 
$$
where $C$ is some constant.

Tropp used this fact without giving any proof or reference. But, after working on this for a while, it doesn't seem something trivial to me. After searching for a while, I found that the desired result seems to follow from the results by [A.C.Kimber](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00533727.pdf?pdf=button) and [C.W.Anderson](https://doi.org/10.2307/3212152.).

However, I think it would be nicer if we can find more direct or an elementary way to obtain the desired estimation.

Any advice, suggestions or references would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi: are you referring to the maximum time between $n$ poisson events ? because, otherwise, the notion of a max for a Poisson is not clear to me ? The event either happens or doesn't happen but there is no value associated with that event unless you want to think of it as 1 or 0 ?

Comment: @markleeds: This is the discrete [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), not a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).

Comment: Just to make it clear, this post is not resolved yet. The sketch proposed unfortunately didn't turn into a proof.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a sketch, but you might be able to turn it into a proof.

The CDF of the maximum of $n$ independent variables is the product of their CDFs, so if they’re identically distributed this is the $n$-th power of their CDF. As $n\to\infty$, we have $F(x)\to1$ and thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\log F(x)^n
&=&
n\log F(x)
\\
&\approx&
n(F(x)-1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Since the distribution of the maximum is very sharp, this has to be $\log\frac12$ near the mean. For the Poisson distribution with mean $1$,

$$
F(x)-1=-\mathrm e^{-1}\sum_{k=\lceil x\rceil}^\infty\frac1{k!}\;.
$$

For $n\to\infty$, this is dominated by the first term, $-\frac1{\mathrm e\lceil x\rceil!}$. Setting

$$
\frac n{\mathrm ex!}\approx\log2
$$

and using Stirling’s approximation for the factorial yields

$$
x(\log x - 1)\approx\log n\;,
$$

which leads to

$$x\sim\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for providing me with the sketch! Could you add the definition of x? It seems to be related to n but not clear how you defined. I believe F is the distribution function of X_i. Also, could you elaborate on "Since the distribution of the maximum is very sharp, this has to be log 1/2 near the mean"?

Comment: @IH: $x$ is the variable that stands for the values the $X_i$ can take. Yes, $F$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the $X_i$.  The sentence you quote is probably the least rigorous part of the sketch. By the distribution of the maximum being very sharp, I mean that it's highly concentrated, i.e. it has low variance, and the maximum is very likely to be very near its mean. That implies that $F(x)^n$ decreases rapidly below the mean of the maximum and increases rapidly above. Somewhere near the mean, it has to cross $\frac12$, so its logarithm has to be $\log\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. What you mentioned the least rigorous part seems to be the most difficult part to justify. If you plug in log n/log log n to x(log x -1), you obtain log n + o (log n) but the small o part is not small enough.